# Значения одного select в зависимости от значения другого

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

Получается в первом селекте из таблицы бд выбирается некоторый тип (`types`).
Во втором селекте из другой таблицы нужно выводить все значения столбца `product`, которым соответствует выбранный тип из 1го селекта (во 2й таблице для каждого `product` прописан свой тип в отдельном столбце).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select.SelectId").change(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/zakaz/zayavka/products/" + $(this).children("option:selected").val(),
      method: 'post',
      data: {
        value: $(this).children("option:selected").val()
      }
    }).done(function(data) {
      $("select.newselect").html(data);
    });


  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>


<select class="SelectId">
  <option selected disabled hidden>select some value</option>
  <?php $sql = DB::select('select type from type');
foreach($sql as $row){?>
  <option value="<?= $row->type?>">
    <?= $row->type?>
  </option>';
  <?php } ?>
</select>
<select class="newselect">
  <option selected disabled hidden>select new value</option>
</select>
```

Это файл newselect.blade.php.

```html
<?php
$sql = DB::select('select product from meat where type = ?',[$type]);
foreach($sql as $row){
echo "<option value = '$row->product' > $row->product </option>";}
```

Роут

```html
Route::post('/zakaz/zayavka/products/{type}', 'TypeController@getProducts');
```

Контроллер

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;

class TypeController extends Controller
{
  public function getProducts($type)
{
  return view('newselect', [
      'type' => $type,
  ]);
}

}
```

Что нужно пофиксить, чтобы заработало? Можно ли чтобы вообще было без отдельного этого файла newselect.blade.php, а то получается что это он и вообще не работает.

Comment: И как php-файл поймёт что такое DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Маршрут
Нужен GET. Во-первых, чисто по смыслу - идёт получение данных, а не отправка. Во-вторых, для работы POST нужно передавать csrf.

```
Route::get('/zakaz/zayavka/products/{type}', 'TypeController@getProducts');
```

Контроллер и шаблон
Они написаны "правильно". В том смысле, что код работает. Но, действительно правильно, было бы перенести всю логику из шаблона в контроллер. И возвращать данные, а не кусок html-кода.
Проверить работоспособность можно в браузере, введя указанный путь: `http://test.local/zakaz/zayavka/products/type_1`. Где `type_1` - "идентификатор" типа (то есть, запрос `select product from meat where type = "type_1"` возвращает данные).

ajax
Тут тоже рабочий код. Только не забудьте `post` заменить на `get`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select.SelectId").change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/zakaz/zayavka/products/" + $(this).children("option:selected").val()
        }).done(function(data) {
            $("select.newselect").html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Должно работать (проверил у себя).
Главное, чтобы запросы `select product from meat where type = "type_1"` возвращали данные. Если в табличке типов есть идентификаторы, то лучше использовать их.
То есть, здесь возможна "ошибка" и я бы немного переделал.

Табличка типов должна содержать два поля `id` и `name`. `id` - уникальный идентификатор. `name` - отображаемое название. Плюс, сколько угодно дополнительных полей.
Табличка товаров должна содержать три поля `id`, `name`, `type_id`. Поле `type_id` - должно ссылаться на `id` в первой табличке.

Тогда, первый селект будет формироваться так:

```
                <select class="SelectId">
                    <option selected disabled hidden>select some value</option>
                    <?php $sql = DB::select('select id, name from type');
                  foreach($sql as $row){?>
                    <option value="<?= $row->id?>">
                      <?= $row->name?>
                    </option>';
                    <?php } ?>
                  </select>
```

А шаблон (newselect.blade.php) будет выглядеть так:

```
<?php
$sql = DB::select('select id, name from meat where type_id = ?',[$type]);
foreach($sql as $row){
echo "<option value = '$row->id' > $row->name </option>";}
```

Comment: Что-то в итоге я не понял, что брать(использовать) если оставить `newselect.blade.php`, а что если его убрать. Если его оставлять, нужно же где-то прописать `view('newselect')`, которое в функции контроллера прописано? Вот тут получается `Route::get('/types/{id}/products', 'TypeController@getProducts')->name('newselect');` ? Или как-то не так.

Comment: Имя маршрута и имя вью никак не связаны. `view('newselect')` - потому что, есть вью `newselect.blade.php`.

Comment: Есть маршрут. Маршрут ведет в контроллер. Контроллер должен вернуть данные. Правильнее вернуть данные, завернув их в json (https://laravel.com/docs/master/responses#json-responses) и уже в скрипте сформировать из них html. В этом случае, никакая вью не нужна. Но можно вернуть данные так, как делаете вы: сразу сформировать кусочек html. Для этого проще использовать вью.

Comment: А в маршруте важно, по какому пути находится эта страница с селектами? `/zakaz/zayavka/products` путь вот такой, значит в роуте указывать его вот так `Route::get('/zakaz/zayavka/products/{id}', 'TypeController@getProducts');`? Или это другое и нужно прописать роут как у вас?

Comment: Маршрут может быть любым. Главное, чтобы он был связан с нужной функцией и именно по нему запрашивались данные из скрипта. Вы можете сделать как у вас, но когда-нибудь в будущем, глянув на маршрут и увидев `products/{id}` вы решите, что по данному маршруту возвращается только один продукт с указанным `id`. Поэтому, я и предложил включить в маршрут `/types/{id}/products` - возвращается список продуктов для типа с указанным `id`.

Comment: Посмотри ролики на этом канале. Мне когда-то помогло. Оно, конечно, уже устарело, но не критично. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NNdTljRzPqE&list=PLD5U-C5KK50X1KcfueA73sGSjBsd8vgVG&index=5

Comment: Вроде бы всё сделал, внёс изменения в первый пост. Но всё равно не работает.

Comment: Слушай, а может ты зря решил делать через ajax? Может в данном случае, достаточно передать все нужные данные при формировании странички? То есть, грубо говоря, заранее сформировать все селекты с продуктами (для каждого типа)...

Comment: Убедись, что в контроллере получаешь нужный идентификатор. Добавил в ответ указание на место, в котором проблема.

Comment: type это несколько разных вещей. Название таблицы для первого селекта, столбец из этой же таблицы, значения которого выводятся в этот селект. И ещё это название столбца во второй таблице. То есть если эти значения совпадают, то во второй селект выводится соответствующее значение из столбца product. В общем, то же самое, что через id вроде бы.

Comment: я имел ввиду, что за `$type` в приведенном кусочке кода? Похоже, что данная переменная вообще не проинициализирована. Во-вторых, обрати внимание, что маршрут для GET, а запрос `method: 'post',` Либо маршрут сделай `Route::post`, либо запрос гетом.

Comment: Вроде исправил, немного поменял первый пост. Поставил в роут `post ` вместо `get` и `$type` поменял на `$(this).children("option:selected").val(),`. Но всё равно второй селект всегда пустой.

Comment: Переписал ответ. Если не работает, говори на каком этапе.  
Javascript реагирует на изменения значения? (можно вставить `alert("Выбранное значение: ");`)  
Если ввести путь в браузере, отображаются данные?

Comment: Всё, заработало, когда метод в скрипте поменял на get

Comment: Так и ещё вопрос теперь появился) Как заставить работать этот скрипт с другим? `$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#pokaz').selectMultiple()
   });` Это стиль для multiple селекта, когда даю `id="pokaz"` зависимому селекту, он перестаёт работать.

Comment: Предыдущие селекторы завязаны на класс, при добавление идентификатора, ничего ломаться не должно: `<select id="pokaz" class="newselect">`. А что вообще хочется сделать? Чтобы второй селект поддерживал множественный выбор? Достаточно сделать так `<select class="newselect" multiple>`.

Comment: Да, если добавить идентификатор ничего не ломается. Но у меня скрипт на `select multipe`, который я скинул выше (там ещё и js файл отдельный для него подключается), и в итоге если я прописываю в этот скрипт добавленный `id` к селекту, то перестаёт работать динамическое обновление второго селекта из 1го скрипта. Проблема обычного `multiple`, что там выбор нескольких значений только с зажатым ctrl работает. Стиль же этот позволяет просто мышкой отметить всё галочками. Или можно такое провернуть без всяких дополнительных js файлов?

Comment: Открой код сформированной странички (после того, как отработает `selectMultiple()`). Там уже нет изначального `<select class="newselect">` - он заменён на кучу кода, который и "выглядит" как красивый селект. Если это так, то уже некуда впихивать кусочек html-кода. Как вариант,.. при получении ответа (ajax), удалять "красивый селект", формировать простой select и превращать его в "красивый" (вызывать `selectMultiple()`). Либо, почитать документацию к скрипту (который делает красивый селект). Возможно, есть функции, для управления содержимым.